# Adding JFilechooser to JFrame glass pane, unable to see Filechooser popup

Tags: java, swing, popup, jfilechooser

I have a `JFilechooser` placed on top of a `JFrame` glass pane. When I select the "look in" popup it seems to be showing up behind the `JFilechooser`. I fixed this a while ago with a solution I found online to force the popup to be a heavyweight component:

```
    try {
        field = PopupFactory.class.getDeclaredField(
                        "forceHeavyWeightPopupKey");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        fileChooser.putClientProperty(field.get(null), true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LibraryUI.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LibraryUI.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

It seems that this solution worked for JDK 1.6 and not 1.7. When I run it now I get the exception: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: PopupFactory_FORCE_HEAVYWEIGHT_POPUP`

I'm not sure what the solution for 1.7 would be to make that popup stay on top of the JFilechooser.

Comment: Why not show the JFileChooser in the JFrame's contentPane via a CardLayout?

Comment: why not with standard JFileChooserplace into GlassPane, can't see there some issue, be sure that GlassPane can't be nest Heavyweight AWT Component, only Swing JComponents, then can't be works correctly in Java6 too (few times asked here)

Comment: I already use the Content pane for something else @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @mKorbel not sure what you mean, I am trying to set the popup of the JFileChooser to be on top when the JFileChooser is on a Glass Pane. Is there a way to force that popup to be heavyweight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on hidden implementation details carries the risk of change without notice :-) If you do it - the obvious recomendation is **don't never-ever** in production code - be prepared to dig deep into the bowels of the source if the old hack stops working.

In this particular case, the change from jdk6 to jdk7 was to move the key from a private field in PopupFactory to a value of the package-private enum ClientPropertyKey. So you have to adjust the reflection code to:

```
public void forceHeavyWeight(JCompoennt fileChooser) {
    try {
        String name = "javax.swing.ClientPropertyKey";
        Class<?> keyClazz = Class.forName(name);
        Field field = keyClazz.getDeclaredField("PopupFactory_FORCE_HEAVYWEIGHT_POPUP");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object fieldValue = field.get(null);
        fileChooser.putClientProperty(fieldValue, true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // doesn't really matter what we do here, lost anyway ;-)
        logSomehow(ex);
    }
}
```

**Update**

After digging a bit, I think that the behaviour (showing the popup in z-order under the component added to the glassPane) is a bug. Same misbehaviour for toolTips set to components in the glassPane as well.

The technical reason is that, once the PopupFactory decided that a lightWeight popup is just fine, it inserts it into the layeredPane of the top-level ancestor of the invoker, no matter whether or not the invoker actually is part of the layeredPane's hierarchy. The excact location in PopupFactoryLightWeightPopup.show():

```
// suitable parent of the invoker, to add the popup
Container parent = null;

if (owner != null) {
    parent = (owner instanceof Container? (Container)owner : owner.getParent());
}

// Try to find a JLayeredPane and Window to add
for (Container p = parent; p != null; p = p.getParent()) {
    if (p instanceof JRootPane) {
        if (p.getParent() instanceof JInternalFrame) {
        // Continue, so that if there is a higher JRootPane, we'll
        // pick it up.
            continue;
        }

        parent = ((JRootPane)p).getLayeredPane();
        // the implied assumption for correct visuals is that the assert below passes
        // would fail if the invoker is
        // located in the glassPane hierarchy
        assertTrue(SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(owner, parent);
    } else ....
    }
    // with the failing assumption above, the popup is inserted below its invoker 
    if (parent instanceof JLayeredPane) {
        parent.add(component, JLayeredPane.POPUP_LAYER, 0);
    } else ...   
}
```

The place to fix would be higher up in the decision chain whether or not a heavyWeight popup is needed: best in `PopupFactory.getPopupType(Component ..)` (that's were the hack above is effective) which unfortunately is private, so there is no way to subclass and make it behave. In fact there is no way at all to *safely* fix it, all approaches I have seen so far require to go dirty and access package/private fields or methods via reflection - which will fail in security-restricted contexts.

Personally, I tend to prefer a dirty factory (accessing super's setPopupType to force a heavyweight `if !isDecending(invoker, layeredPane)` over a dirty clientProperty for two reasons:

- it's jdk-version independent
- it fixes the problem at a single place: installing the custom popupFactory once vs. applying the property for each glassPane

Comment: I fully understand that, the hack is a nice to have anyways, so its not anything critical in production code. Thanks

Comment: +1 very nice edit, thanks, btw are you meaning that changes by using [Darryls Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) could be hacks only, to change the JScrollpanes properties which nested JList/JTable, or to extract those JComponent on runtime,

Comment: @mKorbel ... head-scratching: what do you mean? I don't see much of a connection between this bug and Darryl's utils, could be blind, though :-)

Comment: then there are accesible all JComponents, possible to extract to the local variable and then to change properties for JScrollPane nested JList/JTable that is covering JComboBoxes popup(s???) from the top of JFileChooser, (I searched without luck) can't found this post about properties, locale and to change isHeavy...

Comment: @mKorbel hmm .. do you mean walking the hierarchy and manually call `popup.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)`? That's possible (same as globally setting it to false for all all JPopupMenus via the class method `JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)`) but doesn't cover the tooltips misbehaviour: the corresponding `tooltipManager.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)` results in mediumWeight popups instead of heavyWeight

Comment: I have to look for this thread and to simulating with real code